# Getting products with price range

Tags: price, ce-1.8.1.0, products

I'm getting all products with this code:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addStoreFilter()
->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
$collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');
$collection->getSelect()->limit(12);
```

Can I add price range? Like "price > 1000 && price < 5000" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gt'=>1000));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('lt'=>5000));
```

Answer (score 1):

also you can check this

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('from'=>'1000','to'=>'5000'));
```